# Typescript - Determine Child type based on property given from keyof

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am not sure if this is possible or not but I wanted to be able to take an interface and give extra options to that interface for instance.

```js
interface IRole {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

interface IAddress {
  line1: string;
  line2: string;
  city: string;
  state: string;
  zip: string;
}

interface IUser {
  email: string;
  password: string;

  role?: IRole;
  addresses: IAddress[];
}

const options: FieldOptions<IUser> = {
  name: 'role',
  description: 'This is a role',
  children: [
    {
      name: 'name', // The child element declaration should be the type that is specified by the name
                    // In this case it should be FieldOptions<IRole>[]
                    // But right now it is FieldOptions<IRole | IAddress[] | string>[]
                    // I just need a way to narrow down to what it should be
      description: 'This is the name on the role'
    }
  ]
}
```

Right now I have my FieldOptions interface as such, which I know is wrong.

```js
interface FieldOptions<T, K extends keyof T> {
  name: K;
  description?: string;
  children?: FieldOptions<T[K], keyof T[K]>[];
}
```

I have been trying to find an example of this however all of them that I find have todo with known keys and will use conditional properties for that.  Mine is a little different since it is built on unknowns until the user puts in a type.  Thanks for any help I can get.

Comment: I'm working on it.  You'll need to use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types).  The recursion makes it a little tricky.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you need a type alias instead of an interface, since `FieldOptions<IUser>` should end up as a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types) of structures corresponding to each choice for the `name` field.  And interfaces cannot be unions.

The following is a recursive conditional mapped type which hopefully expresses what you're trying to accomplish:

```
type FieldOptions<T> = T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]-?: {
  name: K;
  description?: string;
  children?: FieldOptions<T[K]>[];
} }[keyof T] : never;
```

The idea is that if `T` is an object type, you iterate over all its property keys `K` and calculate something similar to your previous version, which I'll call `OldFieldOptions<T, K>`.  This produces something like `{email: OldFieldOptions<IUser, "email">, password: OldFieldOptions<IUser, "password", ...}`.  Then we [look up](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) all its property types by indexing into it with `keyof T`.  This produces the union `OldFieldOptions<IUser, "email"> | OldFieldOptions<IUser, "password"> | ...`.

And since `FieldOptions<T>` is recursive, this should work for all subproperties too.

If `T` is not an object we just return `never` (so `children` would be a `never[]` meaning it cannot have any entries).  If `T` is an array this might do weird things, so you might need to tweak it.

Let's see if it works:

```
const options: FieldOptions<IUser> = {
  name: 'role',
  description: 'This is a role',
  children: [
    {
      name: 'name',
      description: 'This is the name on the role',
      children: []
    }
  ]
}; // okay

const badOptions: FieldOptions<IUser> = {
  name: "role",
  children: [{
    name: "oops" // error!
  //~~~~ <-- bad name
  }]
}
```

Looks good.

As I mentioned, you might need to tweak the definition above in case you want to treat primitive or array properties differently.  Right now it works best for plain object types.  You have to think about `FieldOptions<IAddresses[]>`, for example: what should its `name` property be, numbers?

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJICUD2AbFBvAKGWWABMAuZEAVwFsAjaAbiKrlokoGcwpQBzFgF8CBUJFiIUqAIKlSUCFy7JCxbKAgBGbrwEt1mgEy6+IQawTAwAT1P7WPOJHvmDyAF7AADq4sixcGh4JDQAVS5oVVYIWjhgbD93bzhlAHdMKApkHjMLYigcCAB+Sgwi9zh5RWUlMrkFJS4AbQBdYVEETBAeZExvMGBurkoAMWAIbFIAeQGhnoAeVAjoAD5kAF5o4hB2TmQAckLcA4AaVlIlBD457soDgBUAC2AVV+Q4ZGOIM8sXqcUIEozWQrGIamIkN2HHu0J+50hkMuXGuPkGd0Oz3e7zATxQcL6IGQuJQ31+iOICH+jSByDaYOQImIrQIQiYyAA9By+gBrOA2TrDMDIehVWbonpjCZTcXzLhLFZQdZbCFwygAIm+6oRyCpCRpwIhOz2Gsw-S46s53OghSgAEJWFyAH4up3IBYAWg9IqqbA4rCELICtm8KHGkxmt0WD2VyAeyAgAA9ICBSCpMPQAFYQBDC4qqOkAaRIRJ5EBsmBgcdaHtK2z9+0L7mRqKjddyDkp1MBdfDMqj8oezULrVWbWEjOaZYrVYerWQlBAEAAbsxREA)

Comment: This is very interesting. Any idea why the choice of `name` narrows the `children` type in this definition, but not when the OP's includes a `name: 'role' as const` assertion that should [force its type to that literal?](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29510) [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgPAFQDRQNJQgD2BAdgEwGcoBrCEAewDMoEA+KAXigG8AoKTqAQwC40kHLgCMA-P3gIA2qgC6KMpRrS5dNgF8A3GzahIUAMpNWPfiyjCzUAMb8A5HajqU+KxHuP1Tp22sVchMCmsHAGKHbcdgzM7FzBEY7cxH4BwIJxlqxCcZx8UHbCicn+gek5nJmx5Tl5dtZFNiXA2TnqLW3qQA)

Comment: That worked like a charm now to just wrap my head around all the ideas at once, was also able to get the array typedef defined as well with a conditional with infer.

Answer (score 0):

@jcalz beat me to posting but what I came up with is extremely similar.

```
type FieldOptions<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: {
    name: K;
    description: string;
    children?: Required<T>[K] extends object ? FieldOptions<Required<T>[K]> : never;
  }
}[keyof T][]
```

The tricky part is having to use `Required<T>[K]` instead of just `T[K]`.  This is because something like `IUser['role']` is `IRole | undefined` due to the property being optional, but we want to get the options for `IRole` without the `undefined` messing with it.

```
type UserOptions = FieldOptions<IUser>
```

evaluates to:

```
type UserOptions = ({
    name: "email";
    description: string;
    children?: undefined;
} | {
    name: "password";
    description: string;
    children?: undefined;
} | {
    name: "role";
    description: string;
    children?: FieldOptions<IRole> | undefined;
} | {
    ...;
} | undefined)[]
```

I'm assuming that your `options` was meant to be an array with that object in it, because it doesn't really make sense otherwise.  It [passes typescript checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=27&ssc=14&pln=27&pc=18#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJICUD2AbFBvAKGWWABMAuZEAVwFsAjaAbiKrlokoGcwpQBzFgF8CBUJFiIUqAIKlSUCFy7JCxbKAgBGbrwEt1mgEy6%20IQawTAwAT1P7WPOJHvmDyAF7AADq4sixcGh4JDQAVS5oVVYIWjhgbD93bzhlAHdMKApkHjMLVigcCAB%20Sgwi9zh5RWUlMrkFJS4AbQBdYVEETBAeZExvMGBurkoAMWAIbFIAeQGhnoAeVAjoAD5kAF5kZrU2DkoAckLcA4AaVlIlBD457sOAFQALYBUX5DhkY4gzy2epxRAlGarGIu2IxBA7E4yAOkI4Z2QAHpEcgnigEH9SMhJrEIOBkJcENg4FBnPMco9MNQpshGMgwI8ULZvEzHs4SCouCyrDAJlj6DZ6Yy9hAQeDxRKJci0CAhW8EKkUNYKVSaXTxpMZrdFuVcKs2mLJUbwdKAELUMCfYD8R6WkCYNIkS1vDVTWaDYZLLC4ZAAHzQDRqLVafpyenM%20tahuNRulqGQACtqL0QBAIFiPmk4IKwJg2FBCo7SA7ZbnkGk2c7LVxKdT%20aLJZcuNcfB7ATCnm83gyUHCUN0hSgvgcxSJiFGhFGCMyUK6tW2uAt7ustrtmgBpEiygDWEBsmBgqNalDBIso6-cxCbLe1STFGISjRApWQ6AgAEdqMBFKQl-r1yGEAAB6QCApAqJg9AJhACCWsUyBzu68yLm%20n7fumf4bq06yUKmABuzCsCIQjNLu%206HvcrQGtONgssgKxQEhwybAhExutqi7LJEUCrEAA) with my type  `FieldOptions<IUser>`.